# How to list all posts of a category in wordpress shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I need a shortcode that lists all posts of a certain category.

I found this php code that works on page templates but as soon as I add it in shortcodes it doesn't work (and I really need it in shortcode format):

```
<ul>    
<?php 
$catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("31")); //change this
foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li> 
<?php  endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated and tested version of Amin. T's code. Add to your functions.php file.

```
/*
 * Output a simple unordered list of posts in a particular category id
 * Usage e.g.: [posts_in_category cat="3"]
 */
function posts_in_category_func( $atts ) {

    $category_id = $atts['cat'];
    $args = array( 'category' => $category_id, 'post_type' =>  'post' ); 
    $cat_posts = get_posts($args);

    $markup = "<ul>";  

    foreach ($cat_posts as $post) {
        $markup .= "<li><a href='" . get_permalink($post->ID) . "'>" . $post->post_title . "</a></li>";
    }

    $markup .= "</ul>";

    return $markup;

}
add_shortcode( 'posts_in_category', 'posts_in_category_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this (add this to your functions.php file)

```
function posts_in_category_func( $atts ) {
    $category_id = $atts['cat'];
    ?>
        <ul>    
        <?php 
        $args = array( 'category' => $category_id, 'post_type' =>  'post' ); 
        $catPost = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li> 
        <?php  endforeach;?>
        </ul>
    <?

}
add_shortcode( 'posts_in_category', 'posts_in_category_func' );
```

You can call it like that `[posts_in_category cat=1]`